# How can I use Variable Arguments with wpa_passphrase?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I am writing a bash script where I want to take the network's ssid and password as command line arguments, and use this information to do other stuff. Inside my script I want to use the wpa_passphrase command. The problem is that it is not working with variable arguments. Here is what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

wpa_passphrase $1 $2
```

Heres how I am running the script:

```
./script.sh SSID PASSWORD
```

I don't know what might be going wrong. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
wpa_passphrase "$1" "$2"
```

because most any character in SSID or PASSWORD that isn't a letter or number will be interpreted by the shell as something else; the quotes will prevent that extra interpretation.